# Why can't I apply anything to this element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

So I'm making my stopwatch for Rubik's cube. I have a `div` element (records) that should display the time which I want to enter when a button is clicked, but I can't append a `p` element to this `div`, and neither can I apply any CSS to it.

in rubik.js:

```js
document.getElementById("records").appendChild(document.createElement("p").appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${formula.first}.${formula.second}.${formula.third}`)));
```

When I append a child paragraph to this `div` it becomes a `text` element.
the `div` element in CSS:

```css
#records {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 620px);
    height: 130px;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white !important;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The two buttons(the *add current time* and the *remove last time* buttons) have a `position` of `fixed`

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please, split the line of code into several variables to make it human readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild#Returns) method returns the appended node or text node. So this `document.createElement("p").appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${formula.first}.${formula.second}.${formula.third}`))` returns the append text node, and not the `p` element.

Create the `p` element, assign it to variable, then append the text node, and append the `p` element to `#records`:

```js
const formula = { first: '1', second: '2', third: '3' };

const p = document.createElement("p")

p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${formula.first}.${formula.second}.${formula.third}`))

document.getElementById("records").appendChild(p);
```

```html
<div id="records"></div>
```